# Include by \input an header-includes: preamble in a markdown file

Tags: latex, markdown

I have plenty of markdown files starting with a rather long `header-includes`, followed by some included directives:

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fvextra}
- \usepackage{tcolorbox}
- \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}
- \usepackage[margins=raggedright]{floatrow}

title: "Mathématiques  \n55. Les dérivées"
subtitle: ""
author: Marc Le Bihan
geometry: margin=2cm
fontsize: 12pt
output: pdf
classoption: fleqn
urlcolor: blue
---

\input{apprentissage-include}
```

where `apprentissage-include.tex` has such definitions:

```latex
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}

\newcommand{\donnee}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{Purple}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\definition}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
[...]
```

I would like to include the `header-includes` preamble too, to change its content more easily when updates are needed.

I've created an `header-include.tex` containing:

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fvextra}
[...]
---
```

But whatever I've tried :

```
\input{header-include}
\input{apprentissage-include}
```

or

```
---
\input{header-include}
---

\input{apprentissage-include}
```

I'm receiving the message :
`! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

Do I have a way to succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are loading packages in the `header-include.tex` file it needs to go into the header. To get access to the latex syntax of `\input{...}`, you have to put it into the header includes:

markdown file:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \input{header-include}
  - \input{apprentissage-include}  
title: "Mathématiques  \n55. Les dérivées"
subtitle: ""
author: Marc Le Bihan
geometry: margin=2cm
fontsize: 12pt
classoption: fleqn
urlcolor: blue
---

test
```

The `header-include.tex` file needs to use latex syntax, so no `-` or any other markdown syntax

`header-include.tex`:

```
\usepackage{fvextra}
```

The `apprentissage-include.tex` file is the same as in your question

`apprentissage-include.tex`

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}

\newcommand{\donnee}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{Purple}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\definition}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
```